# How to empty ajax loaded form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, reset

How can we empty a ajax loaded form using pure JavaScript or jQuery. 
I have tried `document.forms[0].reset();` and `$('#new-staff-form')[0].reset();` both didn't work it returns `undefined`.

**Update**

```
<div class="box col-md-12 new-staff">
  <form id="new-staff-form" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
                        <input  type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="First name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="l_name">Last Name</label>
                        <input  type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Last name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="user_name">User name</label>
                        <input id="user_name" type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="User name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button id="user-avail" class="btn btn-primary">Check available</button>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#new-item').click(function(){ // works fine until I load new html form using ajax with same ids and class
            $('#new-staff-form')[0].reset();
            $('.new-staff').slideToggle(); // show new form
        });



$('.edit-item').click(function(){ // ajax call this loads everything correctly
            var id = $(this).data('staf_id'); //item to delete
            $.ajax({
                url:url_view_staff+id,
                type:'get'
            }).done(function(data){
                edit_item_id = id;
                $('.new-staff').html(data).slideDown();
            }).fail(function(data){
                $('#errors').html(data.responseText);
                $('.valid-error').slideDown();
            });
        });
```

Comment: It should work if you are using relevant selector and call reset when FORM is available in the DOM. It's just hard to figure out what's going wrong without seeing any relevant code. BTW, not sure by what you mean with "ajax loaded form"?! Now one thing, no element inside FORM can have an attribute name equal to `reset`, could be your issue

Comment: Is the result of #new-center-form[0] an actual form, or just a form's container or child? Because only actual forms provide the reset() interface.

Comment: @A.Wolff Updated my Qtn please check

Comment: Is `#new-item` loaded/refreshed by ajax request? Indeed, is click handler fired after ajax request?

Comment: @A.Wolff Nope , It is not loaded through ajax. click is fired. I tried `$('#new-staff-form')[0].reset();` in firefox console. it gives `undined`. Is it possible to reset ajax loaded form  ?

Comment: @Shanoop Any online link where i could check this? I don't see why you couldn't reset a FORM loaded via ajax and anyway, the FORM should comes empty

Comment: @A.Wolff It is on my local host. I can't host it now. 
What is `[0]`  in this `$('#new-staff-form')[0].reset();` ?

Comment: @Shanoop to return the DOM node. Reset is a DOM node method, not a jQuery function. I'll test to reset a ajax loaded FORM tomorrow if you still don't have fixed your issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49606/discussion-between-shanoop-and-a-wolff)

Comment: @Shanoop after some tests, i have no problem regarding resetting a FORM added dynamically to the DOM. At least, check than `$('#new-staff-form').length` returns 1 after ajax request. Be sure IDs are unique. I'm sorry but cannot help you more. Ok, just seeing you have solved your issue, so it was just a wrong selector...

Comment: @A.Wolff I was setting **value attribute** with some other scripts. And `reset` wont clear form values attributes that was the issue. now I created form clear function. Working fine. Thank you for efforts.

Comment: Miss understood usage of form reset.The code was actually resetting form. But I was setting value attribute this caused issue.

Comment: shanoop, it would be helpful if you indicated the misunderstanding and incorporated it into your question.  I'm having a similar problem and will likely go through the same steps you did.

Comment: @Chris Reset means, small form element's values will be changed into default value not empty value. So if you want to empty your form you want to write a another code for it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Jquery :

```
$('#form_id')[0].reset();
```

Make sure your form id is valid.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myForm").reset();` is giving error **TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null**
jquery I mentioned in question. both works fine until form not loaded through ajax

Comment: can u add the form tag in the question pls

Comment: @A J I added forms tag. I can't add more tags only five allowed

Answer (score -2):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8zLLn/)

```
$('#configreset').click(function(){
    $('#configform')[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: You should have marked the question as a duplicate, not copy someone else answer.

Comment: I don't know how to mark the question as a duplicate :)

Comment: @putvande This is not duplicate question. My issue is with ajax loaded form. This code is working only with normal forms. Most of the question in SO is for normal forms